# Angular2 AfterViewChecked not firing on a directive when binding is complete on RC4

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have an Angular 2 directive that makes the header (th) of a given table to remain fixed when the table is placed within a scrollable div. It resizes the column headers according to the size of the data on the cells, and vice-versa. It was working fine until Angular 2 RC1, but after I upgraded it to RC4 it stopped working.

After a while I realized that the number of "AfterViewChecked" events triggered by the framework has been reduced, probably due to an issue that got fixed. The problem now is that my directive is no longer triggering its recalculation logic to resize the table headers.

**Is it possible to bind or capture an event from the parent's directive table  in order to trigger the recalculation process?**

The directive code is more or less like this:

```
export class TableFixedHeaderDirective implements AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit
...
ngAfterViewInit(): void ...
ngAfterViewChecked(): void ...
onWindowResize(): void ...
...
```

Within these events is where  I call the logic to perform the header calculation, which will basically resize either headers or columns, depending on the width of the data being displayed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An angular directive does not have a View so all of the view related lifecycle hooks will not work, since they don't exist.

See the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#hooks-overview)

## Directives and Components

**ngOnInit**
Initialize the directive/component after Angular initializes the data-bound input properties.

**ngOnChanges** 
Respond after Angular sets a data-bound input property. The method receives a changes object of current and previous values.

**ngDoCheck**
Detect and act upon changes that Angular can or won't detect on its own. Called every change detection run.

**ngOnDestroy** 
Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive/component. Unsubscribe observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks.

## Components only

**ngAfterContentInit**
After Angular projects external content into its view.

**ngAfterContentChecked**
After Angular checks the bindings of the external content that it projected into its view.

**ngAfterViewInit** 
After Angular creates the component's view(s).

**ngAfterViewChecked**
After Angular checks the bindings of the component's view(s).

Comment: The point is that they are called somehow. After the page is completely loaded, if I click anywhere on the page, the ngAfterViewChecked event on the directive is triggered, and the calculation happens as expected. The problem is that I need that to be fired after the data is bound to the table and the new rows are added.

I managed to make it work by using a **settimeout**, calling the `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after 1s, but it doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Comment: You are right! To docs are misleading and wrong... or its an issue in angular but I bet on wrong docs.

Anyway, you can communicate between components and directives, but if you can provide more details, maybe a plunker with more code so I can see the structure...

BTW, note that in a directive you can't control the change detection strategy, this is set by the host component...

Comment: I opened an issue, lets see what they say and I'll edit my answer accordingly. [LINK](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10221)

Comment: Thanks @Shlomi! Let's what comes from that.

Comment: hey as your answer is old i dont know if that was different back then. But as of today, directives with element-selector do have content lifecycles. @angular/material is using this all the time.