# Call directive when host element is rendered

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am injecting a form as host element in my angular directive. I want to retrieve the list of input elements of that form. But, it seems like, the code is being executed before the host(form) actually rendered (i.e, before input elements are created)

```
 constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,private renderer: Renderer2) { 
  let  formElement = <HTMLFormElement>elementRef.nativeElement;   
  let inputFields = console.log(formElement.getElementsByTagName("input")); //This is blank
  console.log(formElement.getElementsByTagName("input"));      //This is working, but lazy loaded
```

Is there any way to execute the logic only after the host view is ready? Something Like, `@HostListener` to some ready event.

Comment: have you tried using `ngAfterViewInit() {}`?

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/38492522/3019006, We can not call View related callbacks on directive, as directive don't have any views. But, surprisingly, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49006974/3019006 works and seem to solve the problem. I am little confused.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38492522/3019006 is incorrect (likely outdated). https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#!#hooks-overview states that all these hooks apply to both components and directives

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Aluan, I am putting it as answer for future reference:
Implement `AfterViewInit` in Directive class.

```
DirectiveClass implements AfterViewInit {
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,private renderer: Renderer2) { 

  }
ngAfterViewInit(){
  let  formElement = <HTMLFormElement>this.elementRef.nativeElement;   
  let inputFields = console.log(formElement.getElementsByTagName("input")); //This also works
  console.log(formElement.getElementsByTagName("input"));      //This Works
}
```